# Switch and Sum in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following Problem in VBA:

Consider the following:

[image: Excel table]

I want to build the sum of every kind. Go through the column B and gather the amount in column A by the kind and after finishing the loop write the sum in front of every kind in  column  E. 
How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: `=SUMIF($B:$B,$D2,$A$A)`.  No vba needed

Comment: exactly but I have to use VBA because this sheet is created by VBA every time. However if it is not possible else where I will use record macro and your suggestion. Thank you

Comment: Why is it not possible to use formulae? In VBA you can easily set a formula for a cell or cells.

Comment: `Range("E4").formula="= SUMIF($B:$B,$D2,$A$A)"` and then `Range("E4:E9).Autofill`

Comment: @Taelsin, How do you mean?

Comment: @maniA Exactly what Scott just commented :)

Comment: Ok nice I will try it I did not know :)

Comment: just a note...  it may be worth defining your last row in the formula, as summing the column can be very burdensome in larger worksheets, especially if it's not needed. For example `=SUMIF($B$1:$B$14,$D2,$A$1:$A$14)` ... Also note a typo in @ScottCraner's original formula ... `$A$A` should be `$A:$A`.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, nice but another question, how can I do it dynamically? it means I have every time diff number of rows not always 14!?

Comment: You will need to either use a advanced filter or copy and paste the whole list then remove duplicates.  At this point try on your own and when you have a specific problem come back ask a new question and post the code with the problem.  Edit: Usually questions that ask to "Code this for me" get down voted and closed here.  You need to show some effort.

Comment: @maniA - [Dynamically Find Last of Row of Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) ... A little sleuthing goes **a long** way, my friend :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, I have it thanks  a lot to all

Comment: What about just using a Pivot Table?  And if you need it in VBA, use the macro recorder while you do it.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, oh thanks that is exactly where I have no idea could you please give me a reference I saw that one friend used it but I did not understand

Comment: I would start with HELP in Excel for Pivot Tables.  But the kind of result you are looking for is exactly what they are designed to do.  If you enter, in Google search, PIvot Table Basics, you'll get about 245,000 results.  Those on the first page should be useful.

Comment: thanks @RonRosenfeld I will check it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B13=E4)*(A2:A13))

That goes in Cell F4.  Fill down.

Answer (score 1):

To get the dynamic unique list
In D2 `=INDEX($B$2:$B$1000,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$B$2:$B$1000),0,0),0))`

To sum by dynamic unique list
In E2 `=SUMIF(B:B,D2,A:A)`

Drag both down

Here are my results (note the values will differ to your results because I only had 1 next to each one because I couldn't be bothered typing in the values in the picture you pasted, please always try to post data that people can copy and paste):

```
a       3
b       4
f       3
d       2
c       1
0       0
#N/A    0
#N/A    0
#N/A    0
#N/A    0
#N/A    0
```

You can wrap it in an IF(ISNA(formula),"",Formula) or an iserr formula, whatever you like to counter the #N/A